# Python: How to pass an argument obtained from a Text Box into an PYODBC Query

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I'm having trouble passing an argument got from a textbox input into an SQL Query to unlock user accounts.

I tested the code with an explicit value for username in the query and it runs successfully.

I appreciate any help!!

```
from Tkinter import *
import pypyodbc as pyodbc
master = Tk()
username = StringVar()
def callback():
    print e.get()

def unlockhrs():
    username = e1.get()
    print(username)
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxx;DATABASE=xxx;UID=domain1\xxx;PWD=xxx')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("update tbl_UserActivity set UserBlock = 0 where UserName =" +username)
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.execute("select * from tbl_UserActivity where UserName =" +username)


#master = Tk()

master.title("HRS UNLOCK")
master.resizable(False, False)
master.minsize(width=300, height=50)
master.maxsize(width=300, height=50)
Label(master, text="USERNAME").grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e1.bind('<Return>', unlockhrs)





Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Unlock', command=unlockhrs).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

Comment: Do a little debugging before posting a question. For example, I recommend adding `print(username)` in `unlockhrs` to verify that `username` is what you think it is (hint: it's not).

Comment: Thanks!! I verified and it says PY_VAR0, but I understood that when using the textvariable = username, anything entered into the textbox would be assigned into username. :(

Comment: I corrected the code, the value now passes. :)

Answer (score 1):

After some troubleshoting and a hint from Bryan:

```
...
def unlockhrs():
    username = e1.get()
    print(username)
....
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e1.bind('<Return>', unlockhrs)
...
```